# how to seperate div button and check box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this data

1. background `<div>`
2. anchor button `<a class="btn-info">Use</a>`
3. 

```
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox"/></div>
    </div
```

if user click on `use` button it `removes class d-none` and opens an other div which have check box but the problem is that in my code the whole div is considered as button and every thing is merged.

I want to separate it. How can I do that?

`separate(background div , anchor , div(d-none) and checkbox)` here is my code

```
<div class="btn-group mid ">
 <label class="btn btn-primary active">
  <a class="btn-info remove-d-none">Use Current Location</a>
    <div class="d-none">
     <span>Visit Clear</span><br><input type="checkbox" class="js-switch2 js-switch">
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: It is because of the label. Also your HTML is not valid, you do not close the d-none div

Comment: sorry i have closed d-none div forgot to write here

Comment: can you change the HTML structure ? if yes, just move the `Use Current Location` link outside the `label`

Answer (score 0):

The `<div class="d-none">` has no closing tag.
Try closing the tag